# DAG (direct acyclic graph) generation

Tags: directed-acyclic-graphs

I have this instructions sequence, I want to construct the DAG

```
    r9 <- 4
    r1 <- r1+r9
    r2 <- r1+r3
..
```

for the second instruction `r1 <- r1+ r9`, how can I construct the node, since `r1` will use itself???

Answer (score 0):

Every time a variable is assigned to it must have a new node declared for it.

Let's give a sequence number to the instructions:

1. r9 <- 4
2. r1 <- r1+r9
3. r2 <- r1+r3

First we create nodes for the constants: 4

Then we create nodes at t=0 for all variables: r1_0, r2_0, r3_0, r9_0

now we create nodes for each assignment:

1. for r9 in t=1: r9_1
2. for r1 in t=2: r1_2
3. for r2 in t=3: r2_3

now we add edges:

1. (4,r9_1)
2. (r1_0,r1_2), (r9_0,r1_2)
3. (r1_2,r2_3), (r3_0,r2_3)

This is required because as we advance in the calculations, the overridden values no longer have meaning.